# invalid volume spec ":/io": invalid volume specification: ':/io'

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker using book docker in practice.

I am working on technique 44 in chapter 5.

I have downloaded sample deb file from net using below command.

```
$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/libeatmydata/eatmydata_26-2_amd64.deb
```

Then run the below command

```
$ docker run -v ${pwd}:/io dockerinpractice/alienate
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume spec ":/io": invalid volume specification: ':/io'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

My docker version is -

Server Version: 17.06.0-ce

My ubuntu version is -

Description:    Ubuntu 16.10

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker -v mounts the source volume to container volume, and these should be absolute folder path

- for ex: docker run -v /home/ubuntu/test:/var/html/ {image name}

else if you want to pass it as PWD then use

- docker run -v $(pwd):/var/html/ {image name}

note : use () not {} because $(pwd) it will execute the command pwd and replace $(pwd)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the braces syntax. Replace `${pwd}` with `$(pwd)`.

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/io dockerinpractice/alienate
```